# I started a new project on google cloud with wordpress, now how do i get it connected to my website i bought and my email

Tags: wordpress

I want to know how to get all the nameservers etc setup on this.  and get all the stuff pointing in the right direction so it can work

Answer (score 0):

Go to your domain where you bay that and change there DNS settings. After your DNS changed update in server you will be able to point out your google could hosted site by your domain.